# Solvability of Groups and the Group Order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The theorem of Feit-Thompson on group solvability states that if $G$ is a finite group of odd order, then $G$ is solvable. And yet we know the case of abelian groups of prime order (isomorphic to cyclic groups of prime order) which are in fact simple and thus not solvable.

Can somebody explain this discrepancy to me ?

Comment: All abelian groups are solvable.

Comment: Simple nonabelian implies not solvable.

Comment: (Simple and solvable) is equivalent to (Abelian of prime order).

Comment: If G is simple, it does not contain, by definition, a proper normal subgroup. Let $Z/pZ$ be the cyclic group of prime order $p.$ All subroups are of order $p,$(exept $\{e\}$)  and thus not proper. I dont understand the shock I provoked. I very probably misunderstood something, but I dont think it deserved the voting. And I didn't get any explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group $G$ is solvable if there is a decomposition series in which sucesive quotients are abelian. So, for instance, if you take an abelian group $A$ (work for a cyclic group of order $p$ for example), then you have $\{e\}\leq A$ as a such composition series, so that $A$ is solvable.
A group that is simple not need to be non-solvable, as we have seen above. And a group that is non-solvable, need not to be non-simple (see $S_5$ the symmetric group).